# Component is being rendered at the bottom of the page when its not supposed to

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two files, one where an API call is made that returns a `div` with a 3rd party `<script>` tag, but when rendering it on another page it's below all components for some reason.

Here is the component that has the 3rd part script with the div

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

class MediaAlpha extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        const renderScript = document.createElement("script");

        const zip = localStorage.getItem("zipCode");

        /*
            TODO:
            1. add TCPA to text
            2. add url
            3. add placement ID
        */
        renderScript.innerHTML =
            "window.MediaAlphaExchange = " +
            "{ data: { zip: sessionStorage.getItem('zipCode')," +
            "text: 'By hitting Get Your Free Quote, below, I provide my express written consent to receive telemarketing calls and text messages (including through the use of an Automated Telephone Dialing System or prerecorded or artificial voices), emails, and postal mail transmitting insurance quotes, or seeking related additional information from me,from this Web site, our marketing partners and re-marketing network, and up to eight insurance companies or their affiliates or representatives at the phone number (including wireless number), email address,and postal address provided by me. I also expressly consent to electronic video monitoring and recordation of my activities on this Site. I also understand that my agreement to be contacted is not a condition of purchasing any property, goods, or services and that I may call (888) 299-0012 to speak with someone about obtaining an insurance quote. I acknowledge that I may revoke my consent by emailing STOP to  optout@quotehound.com. (2) I agree to this websites Privacy Policy and  Terms & Conditions'," + //CHANGE 1 HERE  remove {INSERT} and keep the quotation marks
            "url: 'covermyexpense.com'" + // CHANGE 2 HERE  {INSERT} and keep the quotation marks
            "}," +
            "placement_id: 'YiPFAJc_r0i9fsZr0uP7vvicsinK3Q'," + // CHANGE 3 HERE  {INSERT} and keep the quotation marks
            "sub_1: 'test sub id', type: 'ad_unit', version: '17' };  MediaAlphaExchange__load('mediaalpha_placeholder');";

        document.body.appendChild(renderScript);

        const script = document.createElement("script");

        script.src = "//insurance.mediaalpha.com/js/serve.js";
        script.async = true;
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }

    render() {
        return <div id="mediaalpha_placeholder" className="bg-[#F3F5FF]" />;
    }
}

export default MediaAlpha;
```

and here is where im rendering it

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import $ from "jquery";
import CTACall from "../Components/CTACall";
import MediaAlpha from "../api/MediaAlpha";
import ConnectMe from "../api/ConnectMe";
import ConfettiGenerator from "confetti-js";
import Footer from "../Components/Footer";

function ThankYou(props) {
    let tele = sessionStorage.getItem("phone");

    return (
        <div className="bg-[#F3F5FF] ">
            <div className="bg-[#F3F5FF] z-1">
                <div className=" mx-auto flex items-center justify-center py-5 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-4" id="content">
                    <div className=" w-full space-y-8">
                        <div>
                            <h2 className="mt-4 text-center text-4xl font-extrabold text-gray-900">
                                Congratulations! You have been matched with these partners...
                            </h2>
                        </div>
                        <MediaAlpha />

                        <ConnectMe moduleId="1657" phoneNumber={tele} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <Footer />
        </div>
    );
}
export default ThankYou;
```

here is an image of how its rendered[image]

as you can see the div for the MA is above the footer but it still renders after, any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: You should almost never use `jquery` with `react`.  Please read official React tutorial before usage https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html

Comment: I would look and see if the injection is happening at the script tags location rather than at where your div is. Hard to say because I cant see injection but document.body.appendChild(renderScript) does place the script at the end of the body

Comment: @KonradLinkowski havent used jquery in these files, mustvbe been an accidental import

Comment: @ColinHale super weird cause this worked in another version we have, we just updated our entire code base to hooks, (functional components where needed), but now that started happening!

Comment: So I don't think there is enough info to answer your question. It depends on how "//insurance.mediaalpha.com/js/serve.js" injects into the dom. Maybe make sure its looking for the correct ID or something? It may just inject at end of document if it doesn't find the correct id

Comment: @ColinHale i think ill just contact thier support cause i cant access that, but thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has this issue in the future this is what i did

so in the Component im trying to render i change all
`document.body.append...`
to
`document.getElementById('mycustomdiv').append...`
and works fine now!  Then i wrapped the imported component on the other component inside the div with the custom id i set.